# How to color the data points by a category

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I created the following series of scatterplots/regressions based on the World Happiness Report data for 2021, to illustrate correlations between 4 different features and generosity.

In the dataframe, the second column (:,1) has a categorical attribute which states the geographic region, ei, Western Europe, North America, etc.

I would like to assign colors to the 'regional indicators', so on the graph you can see a bit about the geography aspect as well, since there are too many to have country names (149 points in total).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style 

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) =plt.subplots(2, 2)


# Importing the dataset
pd.set_option('display.float_format','{:.4f}'.format)
df = pd.read_csv('whr.csv')

X = df.iloc[:,7].values
y = df.iloc[:,10].values
X = X.reshape(-1,1)

A = df.iloc[:,6].values
b = df.iloc[:,10].values
A = A.reshape(-1,1)

C = df.iloc[:,8].values
d = df.iloc[:,10].values
C = C.reshape(-1,1)


E = df.iloc[:,11].values
f = df.iloc[:,10].values
E = E.reshape(-1,1)


from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X, y)

regressor2 = LinearRegression()
regressor2.fit(A, b)

regressor3 = LinearRegression()
regressor3.fit(C, d)

regressor4 = LinearRegression()
regressor4.fit(E, f)


#axes 
generosity = df['Generosity']
social_support =df['Social support']
logged_gdp=df['Logged GDP per capita']
life_expectancy=df['Healthy life expectancy']
perception_of_corruption=df['Perceptions of corruption']


ax1.scatter(social_support,generosity, marker="+")
ax1.set_title('Social Support')
ax1.set_xlabel('Social Support')
ax1.set_ylabel('Generosity')
ax1.plot(X, regressor.predict(X), color = '#4E47E6')

ax2.scatter(logged_gdp,generosity, marker="+")
ax2.set_title('Logged GDP')
ax2.set_xlabel('Logged GDP')
ax2.set_ylabel('Generosity')
ax2.plot(A, regressor2.predict(A), color = '#4E47E6')

ax3.scatter(life_expectancy,generosity, marker="+")
ax3.set_title('Life Expectancy')
ax3.set_xlabel('Life Expectancy')
ax3.set_ylabel('Generosity')
ax3.plot(C, regressor3.predict(C), color = '#4E47E6')


ax4.scatter(perception_of_corruption,generosity, marker="+")
ax4.set_title('Perception of Corruption')
ax4.set_xlabel('Perception of Corruption')
ax4.set_ylabel('Generosity')
ax4.plot(E, regressor4.predict(E), color = '#4E47E6')

fig.suptitle('What Impacts Generosity Around the World?', x=.525, y=.98, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='top', fontsize = 15)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.scatter.markers=('+')



plt.show()
fig.savefig('Generosity.png', dpi=300)
```

[image: Generosity Plots]

```
,Country name,Regional indicator,Ladder score,Standard error of ladder score,upperwhisker,lowerwhisker,Logged GDP per capita,Social support,Healthy life expectancy,Freedom to make life choices,Generosity,Perceptions of corruption,Ladder score in Dystopia,Explained by: Log GDP per capita,Explained by: Social support,Explained by: Healthy life expectancy,Explained by: Freedom to make life choices,Explained by: Generosity,Explained by: Perceptions of corruption,Dystopia + residual
0,Finland,Western Europe,7.842,0.032,7.904,7.78,10.775,0.954,72.0,0.949,-0.098,0.186,2.43,1.446,1.106,0.741,0.691,0.124,0.481,3.253
1,Denmark,Western Europe,7.62,0.035,7.687,7.552,10.933,0.954,72.7,0.946,0.03,0.179,2.43,1.502,1.108,0.763,0.686,0.208,0.485,2.868
2,Switzerland,Western Europe,7.571,0.036,7.643,7.5,11.117,0.942,74.4,0.919,0.025,0.292,2.43,1.566,1.079,0.816,0.653,0.204,0.413,2.839
3,Iceland,Western Europe,7.554,0.059,7.67,7.438,10.878,0.983,73.0,0.955,0.16,0.673,2.43,1.482,1.172,0.772,0.698,0.293,0.17,2.967
4,Netherlands,Western Europe,7.464,0.027,7.518,7.41,10.932,0.942,72.4,0.913,0.175,0.338,2.43,1.501,1.079,0.753,0.647,0.302,0.384,2.798
5,Norway,Western Europe,7.392,0.035,7.462,7.323,11.053,0.954,73.3,0.96,0.093,0.27,2.43,1.543,1.108,0.782,0.703,0.249,0.427,2.58
6,Sweden,Western Europe,7.363,0.036,7.433,7.293,10.867,0.934,72.7,0.945,0.086,0.237,2.43,1.478,1.062,0.763,0.685,0.244,0.448,2.683
7,Luxembourg,Western Europe,7.324,0.037,7.396,7.252,11.647,0.908,72.6,0.907,-0.034,0.386,2.43,1.751,1.003,0.76,0.639,0.166,0.353,2.653
8,New Zealand,North America and ANZ,7.277,0.04,7.355,7.198,10.643,0.948,73.4,0.929,0.134,0.242,2.43,1.4,1.094,0.785,0.665,0.276,0.445,2.612
9,Austria,Western Europe,7.268,0.036,7.337,7.198,10.906,0.934,73.3,0.908,0.042,0.481,2.43,1.492,1.062,0.782,0.64,0.215,0.292,2.784
10,Australia,North America and ANZ,7.183,0.041,7.265,7.102,10.796,0.94,73.9,0.914,0.159,0.442,2.43,1.453,1.076,0.801,0.647,0.291,0.317,2.598
11,Israel,Middle East and North Africa,7.157,0.034,7.224,7.09,10.575,0.939,73.503,0.8,0.031,0.753,2.43,1.376,1.074,0.788,0.509,0.208,0.119,3.083
12,Germany,Western Europe,7.155,0.04,7.232,7.077,10.873,0.903,72.5,0.875,0.011,0.46,2.43,1.48,0.993,0.757,0.6,0.195,0.306,2.824
13,Canada,North America and ANZ,7.103,0.042,7.185,7.021,10.776,0.926,73.8,0.915,0.089,0.415,2.43,1.447,1.044,0.798,0.648,0.246,0.335,2.585
14,Ireland,Western Europe,7.085,0.04,7.164,7.006,11.342,0.947,72.4,0.879,0.077,0.363,2.43,1.644,1.092,0.753,0.606,0.238,0.367,2.384
15,Costa Rica,Latin America and Caribbean,7.069,0.056,7.179,6.96,9.88,0.891,71.4,0.934,-0.126,0.809,2.43,1.134,0.966,0.722,0.673,0.105,0.083,3.387
16,United Kingdom,Western Europe,7.064,0.038,7.138,6.99,10.707,0.934,72.5,0.859,0.233,0.459,2.43,1.423,1.062,0.757,0.58,0.34,0.306,2.596
17,Czech Republic,Central and Eastern Europe,6.965,0.049,7.062,6.868,10.556,0.947,70.807,0.858,-0.208,0.868,2.43,1.37,1.09,0.703,0.58,0.052,0.046,3.124
18,United States,North America and ANZ,6.951,0.049,7.047,6.856,11.023,0.92,68.2,0.837,0.098,0.698,2.43,1.533,1.03,0.621,0.554,0.252,0.154,2.807
19,Belgium,Western Europe,6.834,0.034,6.901,6.767,10.823,0.906,72.199,0.783,-0.153,0.646,2.43,1.463,0.998,0.747,0.489,0.088,0.187,2.862
20,France,Western Europe,6.69,0.037,6.762,6.618,10.704,0.942,74.0,0.822,-0.147,0.571,2.43,1.421,1.081,0.804,0.536,0.092,0.235,2.521
21,Bahrain,Middle East and North Africa,6.647,0.068,6.779,6.514,10.669,0.862,69.495,0.925,0.089,0.722,2.43,1.409,0.899,0.662,0.661,0.246,0.139,2.631
22,Malta,Western Europe,6.602,0.044,6.688,6.516,10.674,0.931,72.2,0.927,0.133,0.653,2.43,1.411,1.055,0.747,0.664,0.275,0.183,2.268
23,Taiwan Province of China,East Asia,6.584,0.038,6.659,6.51,10.871,0.898,69.6,0.784,-0.07,0.721,2.43,1.48,0.982,0.665,0.49,0.142,0.139,2.687
24,United Arab Emirates,Middle East and North Africa,6.561,0.039,6.637,6.484,11.085,0.844,67.333,0.932,0.074,0.589,2.43,1.555,0.86,0.594,0.67,0.236,0.223,2.422
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The easiest solution is to select the desired columns and reshape them into a long dataframe with [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html).
- Then use a combination of [`sns.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) and [`sns.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html)

  - `hue` can be used to specify the colors based on region, but this also results in a separate regression line for each, instead of one for all the data points, so the regression line is not shown for `.lmplot`, and is instead plotted separately for each axis with `.regplot`.
  - `seaborn` is a high-level API for matplotlib
- Using `pandas 1.2.5`, `seaborn 0.11.1` and `matplotlib 3.4.2`.
- This implementation reduces the code from 58 to 13 lines.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# given dataframe df
data = {'Country name': ['Finland', 'Denmark', 'Switzerland', 'Iceland', 'Netherlands', 'Norway', 'Sweden', 'Luxembourg', 'New Zealand', 'Austria', 'Australia', 'Israel', 'Germany', 'Canada', 'Ireland', 'Costa Rica', 'United Kingdom', 'Czech Republic', 'United States', 'Belgium', 'France', 'Bahrain', 'Malta', 'Taiwan Province of China', 'United Arab Emirates'], 'Generosity': [-0.098, 0.03, 0.025, 0.16, 0.175, 0.093, 0.086, -0.034, 0.134, 0.042, 0.159, 0.031, 0.011, 0.089, 0.077, -0.126, 0.233, -0.208, 0.098, -0.153, -0.147, 0.089, 0.133, -0.07, 0.074], 'Regional indicator': ['Western Europe', 'Western Europe', 'Western Europe', 'Western Europe', 'Western Europe', 'Western Europe', 'Western Europe', 'Western Europe', 'North America and ANZ', 'Western Europe', 'North America and ANZ', 'Middle East and North Africa', 'Western Europe', 'North America and ANZ', 'Western Europe', 'Latin America and Caribbean', 'Western Europe', 'Central and Eastern Europe', 'North America and ANZ', 'Western Europe', 'Western Europe', 'Middle East and North Africa', 'Western Europe', 'East Asia', 'Middle East and North Africa'], 'Social support': [0.954, 0.954, 0.942, 0.983, 0.942, 0.954, 0.934, 0.908, 0.948, 0.934, 0.94, 0.939, 0.903, 0.926, 0.947, 0.891, 0.934, 0.947, 0.92, 0.906, 0.942, 0.862, 0.931, 0.898, 0.844], 'Logged GDP per capita': [10.775, 10.933, 11.117, 10.878, 10.932, 11.053, 10.867, 11.647, 10.643, 10.906, 10.796, 10.575, 10.873, 10.776, 11.342, 9.88, 10.707, 10.556, 11.023, 10.823, 10.704, 10.669, 10.674, 10.871, 11.085], 'Healthy life expectancy': [72.0, 72.7, 74.4, 73.0, 72.4, 73.3, 72.7, 72.6, 73.4, 73.3, 73.9, 73.503, 72.5, 73.8, 72.4, 71.4, 72.5, 70.807, 68.2, 72.199, 74.0, 69.495, 72.2, 69.6, 67.333], 'Perceptions of corruption': [0.186, 0.179, 0.292, 0.673, 0.338, 0.27, 0.237, 0.386, 0.242, 0.481, 0.442, 0.753, 0.46, 0.415, 0.363, 0.809, 0.459, 0.868, 0.698, 0.646, 0.571, 0.722, 0.653, 0.721, 0.589]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# columns to be used as value variables
cols = ['Social support', 'Logged GDP per capita', 'Healthy life expectancy', 'Perceptions of corruption']

# melt the desired columns from dataframe df
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['Generosity', 'Regional indicator'], value_vars=cols)

# plot the points with color in a FacetGrid
p = sns.lmplot(data=dfm, col='variable', col_wrap=2, col_order=cols, x='value', y='Generosity', hue='Regional indicator', sharey=False, sharex=False, fit_reg=False)

# use regplot to plot the regression line for all points
for i, col in enumerate(cols):
    sns.regplot(x=col, y='Generosity', data=df, scatter=False, ax=p.axes[i], ci=False)

# add plot formatting
p.set_titles(row_template='{row_name}', col_template='{col_name}')  # shorten the column names
p.fig.suptitle("What Impacts Generosity Around the World?", size=16)
p.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.2, wspace=0.2, top=0.9)  # add spacing between plots

p.savefig('Generosity.png', dpi=300)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. That's a beautifully elegant solution ! Thank you ! I learned a lot from this :)

Comment: @Mr.J You're welcome. Glad it works for you.